# IOS best practices for login signup home

Tags: ios, iphone, authentication, uiviewcontroller

I'm building an iphone application, in my AppDelegate i use this code to load my HomeView (if user is logged in):

```
if(isLoggedIn==YES)
{
    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

    [self.window setRootViewController:(HomeViewController *)[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"homeScreen"]];

}
```

In HomeViewController when my user logout i use this code to switch to LoginViewController:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
self.view.window.rootViewController = (LoginViewController *)[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loginScreen"];
```

Could you please advise me the best practices  ?

Thanks

Comment: Set homeview Controller as RootView and present Login screen if user not logged in , after logout button click once again present the LoginView as modal view

Comment: You should NSUserDefaults for this

Answer (score 2):

```
///Appdelegate.h

@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigationController;

/////Appdelegate.m

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
 if(!isLoggedIn)
 {
 UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loginScreen"];
        _navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController];

   }

else
{
  UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"homeScreen"];
        _navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController];

}
 self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];    
}
////logout_action

-(IBAction)myprofile:(id)sender
{
islogged=NO;
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
   MyprofileViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loginScreen"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
```